# "Mapping" arrows to characters

Tags: php, html, css, math, canvas

I don't really know how to title this, so sorry if the title was confusing.

I would like a way to draw various kinds/orientations of arrows depending on the lengths of the strings they're pointing to (amongst other factors).  See the picture below.

[image: Arrows example image]

I can't just make an image (like this one) because the numbers and letters will be randomly generated.  So, I won't know if a number is a 1, 2, or 3 digit number (or if it will have letters attached to it).

**Basically, is there a way to connect the centers of "nodes" (probably the wrong word, but I don't know what else to say) with the start and end of an arrow?**

I'm open to the full gamut of webprogramming for this.  Javascript libraries, Raphael.js, canvas.... best idea wins!

Comment: if it's randomly generated, what is the logic for connecting?

Comment: @ redreggae: That's part of what I'm trying to figure out.  Each "thing/node" would need to be identified (maybe by <span id="__">).  Then I would need to specify which two (or more) should be connected.

Comment: You'd have to identify the on-screen locations of the strings and write some sort of arrow-generator. It's not easy. No one is going to hand you a solution - show some work.

Comment: @Diodeus: I don't know where to begin.  That's why there's no work.  I'm needing ideas.

Comment: Complex problems are often a series of simple problems. Start by finding the location of the text on the screen.

Comment: **After** the numbers are "randomly generated", do you know exactly which numbers/symbols make up each of your math phrases?  Also, do you control where the different phrases are drawn on the page?  If you answer "yes" to both these questions, your solution becomes much easier.  If you answer "no" to the first question, you have no answer except trying very complex character recognition. And how do you determine where you desire the arrows to start and end--do you specify a letter in a phrase, or what?

Comment: @markE: Yes to both.  Does that give you any specific ideas?

Comment: Yes...see my answer for a quick prototype based on html canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This design maps arrows to & from any specified characters in a math phrase**

[image]

This design uses html canvas to draw the text math phrases and connected arrows.

It works by having you specify any character inside a math phrase and calling for either an up or down arrow to be drawn on that character.

```
    // draw an up arrow on the current phrase as character#1
    drawUpArrow(phrase,30,80,1,"red");

    // draw a down arrow on the current phrase at character#5
    drawDownArrow(phrase,30,80,5,"green");
```

You can specify as many arrows as you need.

```
    // draw arrow on characters #1,3,5,7
    drawUpArrow(phrase,30,80,1,"red");
    drawDownArrow(phrase,30,80,3,"green");
    drawDownArrow(phrase,30,80,5,"green");
    drawDownArrow(phrase,30,80,7,"green");
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/dUexE/

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:15px; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.font="14pt Verdana";

    var phrase="(5c + 3)(7n + 2)";
    var connectorPoints=[]
    var connectorPoints2=[]

    // draw start-arrow at character #1
    // draw end-arrows at characters #5 and #12
    drawPhrase(phrase,30,80);
    connectorPoints.push(drawUpArrow(phrase,30,80,2,"red"));
    connectorPoints.push(drawDownArrow(phrase,30,80,10,"green"));
    connectorPoints.push(drawDownArrow(phrase,30,80,15,"green"));
    temporaryConnector(connectorPoints,"green");

    connectorPoints2.push(drawDownArrowUnder(phrase,30,80,7,"red"));
    connectorPoints2.push(drawUpArrowUnder(phrase,30,80,10,"green"));
    connectorPoints2.push(drawUpArrowUnder(phrase,30,80,15,"green"));
    temporaryConnector(connectorPoints2,"green");



    // draw the phrase at X/Y
    function drawPhrase(text,x,y){
        ctx.fillStyle="black";
        ctx.fillText(text,x,y);
    }

    function calcMidX(text,x,letterNumber){
        var text1=text.substr(0,letterNumber-1);
        var text2=text.substr(0,letterNumber);

        var startX=ctx.measureText(text1).width;
        var endX=ctx.measureText(text2).width;
        var midX=startX+(endX-startX)/2;

        return(midX);        
    }


    function drawArrow(x,y,y1,y2,y3,color){
        // arrowhead
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x,y-y1);
        ctx.lineTo(x-5,y-y2);
        ctx.lineTo(x+5,y-y2);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fillStyle=color;
        ctx.fill();
        // arrowtail
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x,y-y2);
        ctx.lineTo(x,y-y3);
        ctx.strokeStyle=color;
        ctx.lineWidth=3;
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    // draw a down-arrow at the specified letterNumber
    function drawDownArrow(text,x,y,letterNumber,color){
        x+=calcMidX(text,x,letterNumber);
        drawArrow(x,y,18,28,35,color);
        return({x:x,y:y-35});
    }

    // draw an up-arrow at the specified letterNumber
    function drawUpArrow(text,x,y,letterNumber,color){
        x+=calcMidX(text,x,letterNumber);
        drawArrow(x,y,35,25,18,color);
        return({x:x,y:y-35});
    }


    // draw a down-arrow at the specified letterNumber
    function drawDownArrowUnder(text,x,y,letterNumber,color){
        x+=calcMidX(text,x,letterNumber);
        drawArrow(x,y,-22,-12,-5,color);
        return({x:x,y:y+22});
    }

    // draw an up-arrow at the specified letterNumber
    function drawUpArrowUnder(text,x,y,letterNumber,color){
        x+=calcMidX(text,x,letterNumber);
        drawArrow(x,y,-5,-15,-22,color);
        return({x:x,y:y+22});
    }

    function temporaryConnector(aConnector,color){
        var pt1=aConnector[0];
        var pt2=aConnector[aConnector.length-1];
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(pt1.x,pt1.y);
        ctx.lineTo(pt2.x+2,pt2.y);
        ctx.strokeStyle=color;
        ctx.lineWidth=3;
        ctx.stroke();
    }


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <p>Red arrow shows start</p>
    <p>Green arrow shows end</p>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**EDIT FROM OP:** If anyone is interested, here is the final fiddle I ended up using: **http://jsfiddle.net/53mQD/2/**  I took out the red arrows and replaced them with lines.  All credit goes to markE.

Comment: This is pretty cool!  I'll aim to play around with this tomorrow for a bit.  I'll mark this as the solution once I've had a chance to implement it.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: I know nothing about <canvas>, but after doing a little research it seems that the straight lines could be replaced with an arc (http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-arcs/), quadratic curve: `context.quadraticCurveTo(288, 0, 388, 150);` (http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-quadratic-curves/), or a Bezier curve: `context.bezierCurveTo(140, 10, 388, 10, 388, 170);` (http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-bezier-curves/).  Any thoughts on replicating the curved arrow effect from the image in my original post?

Comment: The upside of curves is they appear more "orgainic".  The downside of curves is they are more complicated because control points must be calculated.  Curves take up more space than straight lines. Connecting two different phrases (as in your illustration's bottom connector and as in your middle right connector) with curves would require compound curves which are considerably more difficult to architect.  Here is a Fiddle using curves: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/53mQD/

Comment: You're a genius!  I can only upvote once, but I would have my upvote count for 10 if I could.  All I need to do now is to not have the arrow up or down on the "starting spot".  Like replace the arrow with a line coming up from the 5 (and also down from the 3), but I'll try to mess with it from here.  Thanks for everything!